# Access My Content using ecmascript client OM

Tags: javascript, my-site, client-object-model

Is is possible to access the current user's "My site" and "My Content" using the ecmascript client OM?  Specifically I'm looking to create a custom list, that is specific to each user, and wanted to leverage the My Content feature.  I need to be able to access this list using the ecmascript client om.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried similar things and had problems before (think they were permissions related).

If you just want to 'get' data, and are handy with jQuery, use something like [SPServices for jQuery](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) to grab the data from your MySite. You can [get the MySite host using jQuery](http://e-junkie-chronicles.blogspot.com/2011/10/get-mysite-host-with-jquery.html). You'll also need to get the Url to your MySite (relative to the host). I do have code for this somewhere, but you can also find it if you google about a bit. You basically need to access the UserProfile Web Service, pass in the current username, and retrieve the PersonalSite property.